# Editing complex object structure from TYPO3 frontend

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase

Are there best practices for user interface for editing complex object structures in TYPO3/Extbase (like IRRE frontend editing)?

Let's say I have an object A with 1:n-relations to child objects of type B and C.

Ideally I would like to have a page that makes it possible to edit an A (including adding/modifying/deleting B and C instances without persisting on the fly).

I currently have separate pages (for editing A's, B's and C's) and use the corresponding controller's CRUD actions. Is it possible to edit A's including their children while still using the Extbase object model/concept?

Comment: No, I didn't find any consistent documetation on that yet. But since I had the same problem I found your question on the way - I kind of solved this problem for me - I will destill that into an answer, but you might still have to wait a few hours until I'm done.

Comment: That would be great, thanks!